# Can I define a WebElement that is common to many pages in Abstract Page?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

In my test automation framework I have two different pages that extend one Abstract Page. Some web elements are common to both of the pages. My question is, should I define those elements in my Abstract Page ? Or should I duplicate their definition in both of the subclasses that use them ?

If I don't, then how can I access the WebElement defined on the abstract page from the subclasses level where I am writing my methods ? If I want to stick to encapsulation rules it should be declared as private, so there is no access to this element from the subclasses of the abstract page.

Should I create a getter for every WebElement defined on the AbstractPage ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you only put functions in the abstract page that correspond to a generic web page. To me, that would not include any locators. I would just duplicate their locators in each page. Elements on separate pages are not the same element, they just happen to have the same locator.